# Clip and Zip Coordinate system options Geocortex

Tags: arcgis-server, data, clip, web, geocortex

I have the standard geoprocessing service, Clip & Zip, which references a spatial reference folder containing various coordinate systems (in prj). 
The service works in geocortex via the standard 'Extract.xaml' file. However I need the ability to Change coordinate systems on export. The reason being, ESRI Base maps are on WGS so the geocortex instances / map services are WGS.

Anyone had any luck getting clip n zip working with the ability to select a coordinate system via geocortex? We are happy to have the data exporting in its proprietary coordinate system but would prefer the ability to choose a coordinate system, just not the web viewer coordinate system.